# How do I specify which user or group of users can only view certain information on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to switch some users to only view the limited profile. I'm sure this was a feature or is! a feature. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go into `Account` > `Privacy`
- Click `Customize Settings`
- Select the dropdown arrow for the option you want, for instance, mobile phone as shown below.

[image]

- Click `Customize`

[image]

- In `Make this visible to` select the general option you want.
- In `Hide this from` you can add a specific person or a friend list that will not be able to see the item.